# Serve media file from DB on Vert.x

Tags: java, http, vert.x

I have a vert.x server with port `8080` which stores media files on directory `<project>/media/<file_name>` and `media/<file_name>` column value on the Database. Now what would be the solutions to the following problems:

- Need to serve those media files of directory `<project>/media/<file_name>`. While we request `http://<server_ip>:8080/media/<file_name>`, it should return that file.
- While we query the database, it will return the column value `media/<file_name>`, but we need to return `http://<server_ip>:8080/media/<file_name>`; need to build absolute path of the file.

**Note:** these operations we do in the Django REST Framework.

Comment: have a look at 
https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/http/upload

Comment: Not clear if you store in DB only the paths to files, or the files themselves as BLOBs. Please clarify.

Comment: Since the hosting server can be any, on DB we can't store absolute path like http://<server_ip>:8088/media/<file_name>, but to request media file we need to construct the absolute path and hence our browser can request with the absolute path.